# What are the ideal Unit Test Cases for different layers in repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, tdd, agile

can someone suggest the ideal Unit test cases that may fit in across each of the layers . 
(which otherwise can be called as a **standard**).

for instance, in an ASP.NET MVC applictaion using a Repository pattern  -

**Controller** - can assert for View names and format of the data returned to the views , from the controller action methods( i couldnt think of more , if u can please suggest).

**Services Layer** - ?? what can be written. because they in turn depend on the layers underneath.. ( can some one suggest a Unit Case with example for sevices layer)?.

One trivial question to finish off. Irrespective of the layers , the method being tested makes calls to other instance methods/static methods say,

```
public List<string> MethodUnderTest()
{

      instance.SomeOtherMethod();
      StaticMethod();

}
```

in each case it is neccesary to mock the methods calls  by moving that to interfaces .? any thoughts on that . ( coz unit Testing by nomenclature should not depend on anything)

Can some

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend reading the [Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/). It covers this stuff in detail.

Comment: It certainly is a good book and quite a bit easier to read that the xUnit patterns book.

Comment: I read the book and I have to say that I'm still uncertain about the best way to test an MVC app.